# Adding a new row with Formulas on all Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with 11 Sheets in total. I currently have the function to add a new row, but I need the new row to keep the formula of the preceding/following one, how do I go about this?

- Currently made with SelectionChanged on as Specific Cell
- I have to add the row to where the Current Selected Cell/Row is/was

Current Code for Adding rows, not including Formulas at all:

```
Sub InsertRow(ByVal selection)

    Dim cs As String
    cs = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim y As Integer
    y = selection
    If MsgBox("Add Row " & y & " in all Sheets?", _
    vbYesNo, "Add Row") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & y)
        If y < 7 Then GoTo circumv 'Not to insert in Headers
        Range("A" & y).EntireRow.Insert

circumv:
    Next ws
    Sheets(cs).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a function written. Care to share?

Comment: Note that if you use [Formatted Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370) then Excel automatically keeps the formula if a row is added. So this might be an easy way without coding at all (if it's suitable in your situation).

Comment: Added the Code, Sadly Tables are not suitable for my case

Answer (score 0):

I did start the Macro directly in the VBA Editor. You might want to start it e.g. with a double click. See 2nd Answer!

```
Public Sub InsertMyRow() '(ByVal MyRange As Range)

    Dim cs As String
    Dim actCell As Range
    cs = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim y As Integer
    y = ActiveCell.Row
    If MsgBox("Add Row " & y & " in all Sheets?", _
    vbYesNo, "Add Row") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Set actCell = ActiveCell
        Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & y)
        If y < 7 Then GoTo circumv 'Not to insert in Headers
        Range("A" & y).EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A" & y - 1).EntireRow.Copy
        Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        If Not (IsEmpty(Range("A" & y + 1))) Then
            Range("A" & y - 1).EntireRow.Copy
            Range("A" & y + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        actCell.Select

circumv:
    Next ws
    Sheets(cs).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works..kind of, on my Mainsheet i have the last few columns with "='Sheet 1'!I8",'Sheet 2'!I8... and using this throws the formulas out of order. Adding a new row 9 turns I8, I9, I10, I11 to I8, I10, I10, I11

Comment: Please state the formula you are using on the Mainsheet!
How does it look before the rows are inserted?
How shall the formula look like after the insert?

Comment: My Mainsheet has the Formulas "='Sheet 1'!L8", "='Sheet 2'!L8" ... and so on in Row 8, Adding A new Row would make that "='Sheet 1'!L9", however it still stays as !L8 and the next Row after that has !L10 instead

Comment: Is this a possible solution: Copy the formulas on the mainsheet to other rows (e.g. AL8 ... ) of the mainsheet and copy it back as soon as the new rows are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code directly in every worksheet where you want to have a reaction on a doubleclick!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'MsgBox ("Click")
    Call InsertMyRow
End Sub
```

doubleclick on the sheet to enter the code there:

[image: doubleclick on the sheet to enter the code there]